Making a mini-calendar in vba with userform
I'm working on a mini-calendar that is poping up when I click on a date in excel. The mini-calendar is made of userform. When I click on a date in the calendar, it transcribes it in the cell. Everything works fine. However, I would like to be able to click on the little arrows in the calendar to change the months and the years. 
I have already this code written in the worksheet :


And this code in the userform coding window :

I already tried this code but in vain :
Private Sub MonthUp_Click()
’ Diminuer le mois de 1
Dim currentDate As Date
currentDate = DateSerial(UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption, MonthNameToNumber(UserForm1.Controls(« Mois »).Caption), 1)
currentDate = DateAdd(« m », -1, currentDate)
UserForm1.Controls(« Mois »).Caption = VBA.monthName(Month(currentDate), True)
UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption = Year(currentDate)
Feuil4.buildCalendar
End Sub

Private Sub MonthDown_Click()
’ Augmenter le mois de 1
Dim currentDate As Date
currentDate = DateSerial(UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption, MonthNameToNumber(UserForm1.Controls(« Mois »).Caption), 1)
currentDate = DateAdd(« m », 1, currentDate)
UserForm1.Controls(« Mois »).Caption = VBA.monthName(Month(currentDate), True)
UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption = Year(currentDate)
Feuil4.buildCalendar
End Sub

Private Sub YearUp_Click()
’ Diminuer l’année de 1
UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption = UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption - 1
Feuil4.buildCalendar
End Sub

Private Sub YearDown_Click()
’ Augmenter l’année de 1
UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption = UserForm1.Controls(« Année »).Caption + 1
Feuil4.buildCalendar
End Sub

Function MonthNameToNumber(monthName As String) As Integer
’ Convertir le nom du mois en numéro de mois
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 12
If VBA.monthName(i, False) = monthName Then
MonthNameToNumber = i
Exit Function
End If
Next i
End Function


Not an answer to your question, but Month(DateValue("1 " & monthName)) will return the month number rather than looping through each month number.

Just for the translation, mois is month in french and it's a five day calendar starting from monday to friday. Also, Année is Year in french.

Finally, it works with this code in the userform coding area:
Private Sub IblDown_Click()
Dim strd As String
Dim iMonth, iYear, iStartofMonthDay As Integer
Dim startOfMonth, trackingDate As Date
Dim cDay As control

strd = Mois.Caption
Mois.Caption = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate(strd)), "mmmm yyyy")

iYear = Year(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate(strd)))
iMonth = Month(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate(strd)))

startOfMonth = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, 1)
iStartofMonthDay = Weekday(startOfMonth, vbMonday)

trackingDate = DateAdd("d", -iStartofMonthDay + 1, startOfMonth)
For i = 1 To 30
    ' Skip weekends
    While Weekday(trackingDate) = 7 Or Weekday(trackingDate) = 1 ' If it's Saturday or Sunday
        trackingDate = DateAdd("d", 1, trackingDate) ' Skip to next day
    Wend

    Set cDay = MiniCalendrier.Controls("Jour" & i)
    cDay.Caption = Day(trackingDate)
    cDay.Tag = trackingDate
    
    ' Check if the month of the trackingDate is different from the current month
    If Month(trackingDate) <> iMonth Then
        cDay.ForeColor = 8421504 ' Change the color to gray
    Else
        cDay.ForeColor = 0 ' Change the color to black
    End If

    trackingDate = DateAdd("d", 1, trackingDate)
Next
End Sub

Private Sub IblUp_Click()
Dim strd As String
Dim iMonth, iYear, iStartofMonthDay As Integer
Dim startOfMonth, trackingDate As Date
Dim cDay As control

strd = Mois.Caption
Mois.Caption = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(strd)), "mmmm yyyy")

iYear = Year(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(strd)))
iMonth = Month(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(strd)))

startOfMonth = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, 1)
iStartofMonthDay = Weekday(startOfMonth, vbMonday)

trackingDate = DateAdd("d", -iStartofMonthDay + 1, startOfMonth)
For i = 1 To 30
    ' Skip weekends
    While Weekday(trackingDate) = 7 Or Weekday(trackingDate) = 1 ' If it's Saturday or Sunday
        trackingDate = DateAdd("d", 1, trackingDate) ' Skip to next day
    Wend

    Set cDay = MiniCalendrier.Controls("Jour" & i)
    cDay.Caption = Day(trackingDate)
    cDay.Tag = trackingDate
    
    ' Check if the month of the trackingDate is different from the current month
    If Month(trackingDate) <> iMonth Then
        cDay.ForeColor = 8421504 ' Change the color to gray
    Else
        cDay.ForeColor = 0 ' Change the color to black
    End If

    trackingDate = DateAdd("d", 1, trackingDate)
Next
End Sub

